# Enabling X-Ray support in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-xray

I want to get some X-Ray traces of my Lambda function. From reading the documentation it seems I can just enable active tracing in the configuration and it should record it automatically without any new code deploys correct?

Only if I want custom sub segments would I explicitly make some X-Ray calls in the lambda function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, with the following caveats:

1. You need to check the **Enable Active Tracing** checkbox in the Lambda console.  From your function in the console > *Configuration* tab > *Advanced* dropdown/section > check **Enable Active Tracing** checkbox > *Save*.
2. When you follow the step above, the console will advise that the IAM policy that the function executes under will be modified.  If you're using a role created by the console when creating a function, you may need to modify the role manually.  Either create a new policy and attach it to the role, create an inline policy attachment, or edit the existing policy for the role with a SID like this (this is an example - use globs in IAM policies with great care):

   ```
   {
       "Sid": "AllowXRay",
       "Resource": "*",
       "Action": [
           "xray:PutTraceSegments",
           "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
       ],
       "Effect": "Allow"
   }
   ```

After following these steps, I was able to see full traces of my function in the XRay console.

Comment: Adding these worked. Unfo, the incoming JSON is not logged...add to the one Statement object already there. "xray:PutTraceSegments",
        "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"